# Cordova/Ionic resources

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic to generate resources (icon and splash). I'm using ionic v2.1.0 and cordova v6.4.0.

Until now I've been using (it was working in previous versions):

```
cordova platform add android
ionic resources
```

This was adding android with this version:

```
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms/android
    Package: ...
    Name: ...
    Activity: MainActivity
    Android target: android-24
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Android project created with cordova-android@6.0.0
```

In previous cli versions, `ionic resources` was generating corresponding entries in `config.xml` and the resources were placed correctly.

But after upgrading cordova and/or ionic cli, the resources for android have not being copied, so icon and splash remain as cordova ones. I've seen [this thread](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/android-resources-not-copying-properly-to-platforms-folder/71563/3) and it says to remove android platform and then use this command:

```
cordova platform add android@latest
```

So this adds this platform:

```
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms/android
    Package: ...
    Name: ...
    Activity: MainActivity
    Android target: android-25
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Android project created with cordova-android@6.1.0
```

And successfully copies the icons and splash. The problem is that this creates an extra `res` folder:

```
├── bower.json
├── config.xml
├── gulpfile.js
├── hooks
├── ionic.config.json
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── platforms
├── plugins
├── res
│   ├── drawable-land-hdpi
│   ├── drawable-land-ldpi
│   ├── drawable-land-mdpi
│   ├── drawable-land-xhdpi
│   ├── drawable-land-xxhdpi
│   ├── drawable-land-xxxhdpi
│   ├── drawable-port-hdpi
│   ├── drawable-port-ldpi
│   ├── drawable-port-mdpi
│   ├── drawable-port-xhdpi
│   ├── drawable-port-xxhdpi
│   ├── drawable-port-xxxhdpi
│   ├── mipmap-hdpi
│   ├── mipmap-ldpi
│   ├── mipmap-mdpi
│   ├── mipmap-xhdpi
│   ├── mipmap-xxhdpi
│   └── mipmap-xxxhdpi
├── resources
├── scss
└── www
```

So my question are:

- What is the purpose of this extra generated `res` folder?
- Can I safely remove `res` folder?
- How can I manage now if I want a different icon for android and for ios? (in older cases I was copying generated resources for android in backup folder, generating new resources for ios and then mixing them and making `cordova prepare`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. There is no purpose, it's a bug and it should be generated in the platforms/android folder
2. Yes you can
3. You can add your splash.png and icon.png to the `resources` folder if both need to be the same. Add them to resp. `resources/android` and `resources/ios` in stead if they need to be different. And then run `ionic resources`

See below for the solution:

You updated to the latest version of Cordova, but not to the latest version of Android platform. Do this to update to version 6.1.0:

```
cordova platform update android@6.1.0
```

After that the resources will be uploaded to the res directory in platforms/android and you can safely remove the res directory from your project root.

**Edit**

This issue has been fixed in Cordova 6.5.0.

Update your project to Cordova 6.5.0 using following commands.

```
npm install -g cordova
```

If you already have the project built using cordova earlier version you have to update the android platform of your project.

```
cordova platform update android@6.1.1
```

Comment: That's not working: when running `ionic resources` again, it regenerates all resources (no matter if they are already generated, so they are overwritten)

Comment: Make sure you have both platforms installed and have no icons in resources folder itself. Then add the icon.png to the android and ios folder within the resources folder and run ionic resources. And yes, the resources will be overwritten in both folders and that's what you want. Upon build the resources will be copied to the right folders in both platforms. For more info: http://blog.ionic.io/automating-icons-and-splash-screens/